# How to stop firing the object keys if I start firing the second object keys using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have module where I need filter the data, base on date value and via seaching the words. Right now I experience problem. by the way I using laravel for the backend and React js for front end. but I will give you the scenario happen right now.

**1. When I start fire searching the data this is working properly.**

[image: First Scenario]

**2. When I Click the date filter the data is filtering base on the date value.**

[image: Second Scenario]

**3. This is the problem, When I try to change the searching text value in the textbox the data is not filtering anymore, how to solve that problem. my first thinking to solve it is to make the date filter null but I really don't know how to do it. but to make more understandable I will show you guys my code.**

[image: Last Scenario]

Code Sample:

```
let { loadReceiveChecks, receiveCheckResponse, keyWords, searchWord } = this.props

  let keyStatus = keyWords.toLowerCase();


    if(keyStatus) {
    // this is for date range
    return Object.keys(receive_date).some(
        (key) =>
        typeof receive_date[key] === "string" &&
        receive_date[key].toLowerCase().includes(keyStatus)
    );
}else if(searchWord) {
    // this is for search text input box
    return  Object.keys(item).some(
        (key) =>
        typeof item[key] === "string" &&
        item[key].toLowerCase().includes(searchWord)
    );
    
}else {
    // return all the list data.
    return Object.keys(item).some(
        (key) =>
        typeof item[key] === "string" &&
        item[key].toLowerCase().includes(searchWord)
    );
}
```

Comment: Is `keyStatus` a state variable? Can you post more code? Maybe a small codepen?

Comment: yes your correct the keyStatus is a state variable (props)

Comment: @Gh05d I add more details for the variable

Comment: Can you try passing a state update function for `keyWords` down and set it to null before you return the `Object.keys` in the `keyStatus` check?

Comment: @Gh05d can give example.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information I have, I conclude that your best option is to set the state to null when the date range was triggered. It could look like this:

```
let {
  loadReceiveChecks,
  receiveCheckResponse,
  keyWords,
  searchWord,
  updateParentState, // function which contains this.setState()
} = this.props;

let keyStatus = keyWords.toLowerCase();

if (keyStatus) {
  updateParentState(null); // set parent state to null
  // this is for date range
  return Object.keys(receive_date).some(
    key =>
      typeof receive_date[key] === "string" &&
      receive_date[key].toLowerCase().includes(keyStatus)
  );
} else if (searchWord) {
  // this is for search text input box
  return Object.keys(item).some(
    key =>
      typeof item[key] === "string" &&
      item[key].toLowerCase().includes(searchWord)
  );
} else {
  // return all the list data.
  return Object.keys(item).some(
    key =>
      typeof item[key] === "string" &&
      item[key].toLowerCase().includes(searchWord)
  );
}
```

Comment: updateParentState what do you mean for parentStatus Update?

Comment: the `setState` function of the parent for the `keyStatus` variable.

Comment: it says that updateparentstats is not function

Comment: Well have you defined it in the parent class? You have to pass the child component this function. It is nothing that is there by default.